# How to use a prefix in derived class constants in PHP?

Tags: php, inheritance, constants, prefix

I would like to create a helper class for icon constants, but there is two types for every icon. I try to avoid duplication, so I make some inheritance.

As I understand the concept of constanst, this will never work, but I do not know what would be a better solution. Could you suggest a clean solution for this problem? The aim would be to avoid the need for remembering every constant. Thanks!

```php
abstract class Heroicon
{
    protected const PREFIX = "";

    public const ACADEMIC_CAP = self::PREFIX . "academic-cap";
    public const ADJUSTMENTS = self::PREFIX . "adjustments";
    // ... +200 rows
}

class HeroiconSolid extends Heroicon
{
    protected const PREFIX = "heroicon-s-";
}

class HeroiconOutline extends Heroicon
{
    protected const PREFIX = "heroicon-o-";
}

echo HeroiconSolid::ACADEMIC_CAP; // "academic-cap" instead of "heroicon-s-academic-cap"
```

Comment: `self::` will always refer to the class where the definition is made. Use `static::` to refer to the currently used extending class.

Comment: Why dont you have regular class as superclass ? Abstract classes need at least one abstract method.

Comment: @IndraKumarS an abstract class doesn't _need_ to have an abstract method.  It can have only concrete methods, or not have any methods at all. ([See demo](https://3v4l.org/ZmfWJ).) _However, any class with an abstract method must be declared abstract_. E.g. a class inherits an abstract class and doesn't define all concrete methods to match, that subclass must also be abstract.  I imagine OP would define the base class as abstract _because it shouldn't be directly instantiated_.

Comment: Since class constants are defined at compile-time, late static bindings can't be used. The value of a `const` (unlike `define`) can only be a fixed value available at compile time, and as such `static::` fails. Just use variables instead --- or a getter that prepends the prefix.